# Populate a html dropdownlist from a comma delimted JSON object with distinct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON object that returns several key value pairs. One of which is a Languages key and this contains comma separated values e.g "English, Hindi,French" etc

What I require is to get the distinct values from the Language keys value and then into the following dropdown list.

The following is inputing the Language values into a dropdown but not handling the comma separating values, can someone help please.

Select a language_

```
   $('#combolist-languages').html(function () {

        var ret = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>',
            u = user.slice(),
            arr = [];

        (function get() {
            if (u.length) {
                var v = u.shift();
                if ($.inArray(v.Languages, arr) == -1) {
                    arr.push(v.Languages);
                    ret += '<option value="">' + v.Languages + '</option>';
                }
                get();
            }
        }());

        return ret;
    });
```

Example link -

31.222.187.42/hca-consulting/Farm/index.html

NOTE the following returns all the records from the db: Search by Name > Browse Names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript spilt function and put the values into the array then pass it to the dropdown list.

For json key value pairs you can separate by "."